# Prevent net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED on rails UJS if a mobile client loses internet connection just a few seconds during ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an issue with a Rails UJS ajax request.

My use case is that if a user on his mobile triggers the ajax request by clinking on a link(see below for the code), then, **while the request is trying to access the server**, if by any chance and it is often the case, you lose your network connection for even a second, then my modal closes without waiting any further (maybe the client would have gotten the network connection 200ms after...).

I would like to tell Rails UJS: 'try to connect to the server at least 10 seconds' before giving up to try.

Indeed that's a pretty common situation: you trigger the ajax, you see the modal with 'loading data' and boum you loste for & second the network connection. so far I managed to proviude for the case where the user is offline when he clicks the button triggering the ajax but I fail to deal with the case described above, i.e where he's online when he tirggers the ajax but WHILe the ajax tries to retrieve data, then he gets disconnected for a very short time.

How to do this ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="zone" class="has-js">  
          <%= link_to image_tag(smallest_src_request),
              deal_modal_path,
              remote: true
</div>
```

**deal_modal.js.erb**

```
var isOnLine = navigator.onLine;
if (isOnLine) {
  // if client has network connection         
  ModalWhenConnected();
} else { // for client disconnected WHEN triggering call to server, invite to reconnect
  modalMessageWhenNotConnected();
}

//using hubspot Messenger: http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/
function ModalWhenConnected() {
  var msg;
  msg = Messenger().run({
    action: $.ajax,
    successMessage:  '<%= j render partial: "deals/deal_messages" %>',
    progressMessage:  '<div class="loading-dots">Loading&nbsp;<span>.</span>&nbsp;<span>.</span>&nbsp;<span>.</span></div>',

  }); 

}


function modalMessageWhenNotConnected() {
  var msg;
  msg = Messenger().post({
    message:            "It seems you lost your Internet connection. Please connect and try again.",
    hideAfter:          3,
    type:               'error'
  });
}
```

Error I get

```
GET http://localhost:3000/deals/deal5/ net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```